# Inequality of numbers.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Prove that 
           $6^a-7^a+2\cdot 4^a-3^a-5^a\ge0$ for $-\frac{1}{2}\le a\le0$. (May be Jensen's inequality help but need help how to apply.)

Comment: As mentioned, your inequality is false.  the sign has to be reversed $\le$ for it to hold true.  Check with $a=-1$, for e.g.

Comment: @Macavity I edited my question please help.

Comment: @MuhammadCamran The inequality is still incorrect. You can just plug in $a=-1$ and check.

Comment: @Ojas but may be some extra condition is required as it is true for a= -1/2.

Comment: The modified question is still wrong. For $a=-1$, the expression on the left is $-\frac1{105}$, which is not $\ge0$.

Comment: @robjohn please check for a=-1/2

Comment: @MuhammadCamran: if you need it for a particular value of $a$, why not just compute it for that value? Plotting the function, shows that it is greater than $0$ for $-0.683\le a\le0$.

Comment: @robjohn I need the proof for whole interval where it is true. :-(

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have the inequality backwards. The inequality
$$
4^a=\left(\frac{3+5}2\right)^a\le\frac{3^a+5^a}2
$$
follows from the convexity of $x^a$ for $a\lt0$.

Comment: Is my question is wrong? Because I need forward inequality which I mentioned.

Comment: As I said, you have the inequality backwards. If you *need* the inequality as it is given in the question, then you *need* to look for another approach to whatever you're proving.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(x) = x^a$. Then $f'(x) = a.x^{a-1}$. By mean value theorem, we know that $\frac{4^a - 3^a}{4-3} = f'(x_1)$ for some $x_1$ in the interval $(3,4)$. Also, $\frac{5^a - 4^a}{5-4} = f'(x_2)$ for some $x_2$ in the interval $(4,5)$. As $a < 0$, we can say that $a.x_1^{a-1} \le a.x_2^{a-1}.$ Thus, $4^a - 3^a \le 5^a - 4^a.$

Comment: This still shows that the inequality is backwards. If $a\lt0$, then $x_1\lt x_2$ means that $ax_1^{a-1}\lt ax_2^{a-1}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry about the goof up.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! :)

Comment: @robjohn I edited it as previous one was wrong please help.

Comment: @robjohn you are absolutely right but for a= -1/2 its true also for some interval.